# Numpy: cannot import name 'mixins' from partially initialized module 'numpy.lib' when using pandas with sqlalchemy database

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, import, sqlalchemy

I'm encountering this problem when trying to use pandas within a Flask_sqlalchemy website.
I want to use the pandas functions to organise data and even run the queries in my app.db using pd.read_sql() with the sqlachemy query object.statement passed into the function so I get a dataframe directly out of the query but I have to pass the db.session into the pandas function in order to do this..so can't avoid importing app.db and pandas at the same time.
It seems to be causing a circular import when I try to register the  Blueprint for this @route with the app where the routes contain any functions that import pandas, due to "numpy mixins" which i think is clashing with Sqlalchemy-mixins.

I'm running python 3.9, with flask_sqlalchamy  2.5.1 and pandas 1.4.2 with numpy 1.22.4.

I have tried various ways of organising my code, and nearest I've got is putting the pandas import into the route function (LAME!!) But at least the web page runs - until it calls the function which uses pandas at which point I get the exact same error.  I'm starting to pull my hair out now.

a version of my app.py:

```
    from flask import Flask
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
    import config
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    app.secret_key = "something"
    app.config.from_object(config.Config)
    
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    
    
    # set up database models
    ..Classes set up here removed for brevity...
    
    
    # add bootstrap
    Bootstrap(app)
    
    # import blueprints from package
    
    # register blueprints with app

    from data_import.import_view import data_import
    app.register_blueprint(data_import)
    
    from data_access.query_views import queries
    app.register_blueprint(queries)
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
         app.run(debug=True, host="localhost", port=5009)
```

Comment: I managed to sort this, I'm not exactly sure how but it was something to do with my environment. I was running venv in pycharm. I moved the venv to a different location and re-added the dependencies and it then worked. I think it might have been because I was initially using sql_alchemy as well as flask_sqlalchemy and I'm now just using flask_sqlalchemy

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. just uninstalled numpy and pandas packages and installed again.